# Autowired RestTemplate returns incorrect ResponseErrorHandler

Tags: spring, error-handling, autowired, resttemplate, inject

everyone. I am now working in a Spring Boot project that one of the function is to send some HTTP requests to third party API and get the responses.

I decided to use `RestTemplate` as the http client and I created a bean for `RestTemplate` in a java file with `@Configuration`

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()));
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = restTemplate.getInterceptors();
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(interceptors)) {
        interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    interceptors.add(new RequestLoggingInterceptor());
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RestResponseErrorHandler());

    return restTemplate;
}
```

Custom error handler and logging interceptor are set in `restTemplate`. Then, I injected the `RestTemplate` into my service class by

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

However, I found that my custom error handler is not working properly and I tried to check the error handler by

```
ResponseErrorHandler customErrorHandler = restTemplate.getErrorHandler();
```

I found that the`ErrorHandler` is still `DefaultResponseErrorHandler` but not my custom errorHandler. Why? Is there anything wrong?

**Updated**

Below are my custom error handler and logging interceptor

```
public class RestResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

@Override
public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    if (!response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    if (!response.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)) {
        throw new RestResponseErrorException(response.getStatusCode() + "" + response.getStatusText());
    }
}
}
```

and

```
public class RequestLoggingInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
    throws IOException {
    logRequest(request, body);
    ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
    logResponse(response);
    return response;
}

private void logRequest(HttpRequest request, byte[] body) throws IOException {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Request begin -----------------------------");
        log.debug("URI:{}", request.getURI());
        log.debug("Method:{}", request.getMethod());
        log.debug("Headers:{}", request.getHeaders().toString());
        log.debug("Request body:{}", new String(body, "UTF-8"));
        log.debug("Request end -----------------------------");
    }
}

private void logResponse(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Response begin  -----------------------------");
        log.debug("Status code:{}", response.getStatusCode());
        log.debug("Status text:{}", response.getStatusText());
        log.debug("Headers:{}", response.getHeaders().toString());
        log.debug("Response body:{}", StreamUtils.copyToString(response.getBody(), Charset.defaultCharset()));
        log.debug("Response end -----------------------------");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: could you add the codebase for your interceptor and your custom error handling?

Comment: Then the `RestTemplate` you are using isn't the one you configured. Please add additional code and configuration to show how things are loaded and configured.

Comment: @rieckpil interceptor and error handler are added in above

Comment: Did you find answer for this ?